# Xpath in mule anypoint studio

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

I need to use a choice router to route messages based on a particular field value in input XML. I am using latest version of anypoint studio. I am not able to use XPath to retrieve and compare the value in a particular field and then route it accordingly. Can someone let me know how to use Xpath to compare the carrier field to UPS. Here is the sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deliver-order xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2"
google-order-number="841171949013218">
<tracking-data>
<carrier>UPS</carrier>
<tracking-number>Z5498W45987123684</tracking-number>
</tracking-data>
<send-email>true</send-email>
</deliver-order>
```

I need to retrieve carrier field from the above xml. I am using xpath expressiosn in choice router like 
    #[xpath('/deliver-order/tracking-data/carrier' == 'UPS']

Comment: Your XPath fails to select anything because you neglected to declare the `http://checkout.google.com/schema/2` namespace. Read the documentation of Anypoint Studio to find out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the value of `<carrier>` and printed in console from logger ... also routed the message based on field value .. Here is what I did :-
I have taken the **xml** as a **file** and my Mule config is :-

```
    <file:connector name="File_Global" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="aaFlow1" doc:name="aaFlow1">
   <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File_Global" doc:name="File"  path="E:\backup\test">
          <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="input.xml" caseSensitive="false"/>
  </file:inbound-endpoint>
<logger message="Trying to process : #[xpath://.[xpath:local-name()='deliver-order']/*[xpath:local-name()='tracking-data']/*[xpath:local-name()='carrier']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> <!--Print the value of carrier -->

<choice doc:name="Choice">
  <when expression="#[xpath://.[xpath:local-name()='deliver-order']/*[xpath:local-name()='tracking-data']/*[xpath:local-name()='carrier'] ='UPS']">
   <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
     <logger message="MATCHED" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
  </processor-chain>
</when>
<otherwise>
   <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
 <logger message="NO MATCH" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
 </processor-chain>
</otherwise>
</choice>
</flow>
```

Comment: Hi Anirban,   Thank you so much for the response. I am able to get the logger message as UPS but the choice filter is failing with the following error: 'Unexpected '#[xpath://.[xpath:local-name()='deliver-order']/*[xpath:local-name()='tracking-data']/*[xpath:local-name()='carrier'] = 'UPS']' (org.jaxen.saxpath.XPathSyntaxException)
  org.jaxen.saxpath.base.XPathReader:1084 (null)'

Comment: here is my configuration xml:''

Comment: here is my configuration xml for the choice component:'<choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when evaluator="xpath" expression="#[xpath://.[xpath:local-name()='deliver-order']/*[xpath:local-name()='tracking-data']/*[xpath:local-name()='carrier'] = 'UPS']">
            <logger level="INFO" message="UPS order" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </when>'

Comment: Never mind Anirban....I am able to get it working now...It was with the choice configuration, I had to modify that a bit....thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can clean-up the xpath expression by using the `mulexml:namespace-manager` element:http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XML+Namespaces

I had to ad a

```
 <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
```

element to be able to parse the .xml (MuleStudio 3.5)

My complete flow:

```
<file:connector name="File_Global" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" />

<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
   <mulexml:namespace prefix="gco" uri="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2"/>
  </mulexml:namespace-manager>

<flow name="aaFlow1" doc:name="aaFlow1">
   <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="File_Global" doc:name="File"  path="/Users/vmbram/Documents">
          <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="input.xml" caseSensitive="false"/>
  </file:inbound-endpoint>

<logger message="Trying to process : #[xpath('/gco:deliver-order/gco:tracking-data/gco:carrier').text]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> <!--Print the value of carrier -->

<choice doc:name="Choice">
  <when expression="#[xpath('/gco:deliver-order/gco:tracking-data/gco:carrier')]">
   <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
     <logger message="MATCHED" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
  </processor-chain>
</when>
<otherwise>
   <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
 <logger message="NO MATCH" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
 </processor-chain>
</otherwise>
</choice>
</flow>
```

Comment: <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/> is optional .. not required

Comment: you're right, no dom-to-xml needed, i didn't test right.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath expression is wrong. Use this one /deliver-order/tracking-data/carrier/text() to get the actual carrier, not the node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use and xpath expression such as:

```
[xpath('/deliver-order/tracking-data/carrier/**text()**' == 'UPS']
```